# How to install a lot of packages from a list in octave?

Tags: octave, package

I would want to install a few packages in an automated way and i was trying do this using a simple for loop. As shown below.

```
   pkgs = '../pkgs';
   names = dir(fullfile(pkgs, '*.tar.gz')); 
   n = numel(nomes);
   for i = 1:n
        pkg install names(n).name
   end
```

This is first attempt that returns to me this 8 times

```
warning: file names(n).name does not exist
```

And i'm looking for a way to get the `ans` value of names.name.

Comment: btw, many packages have dependencies, for example signal depends on control so it's very likely that you run into problems if you just install *.tar.gz

Comment: Yes, then is really necessary  make some "sort" on packages list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of all that code, you can use 'glob()' to get the list of tarballs, and then a single `pkg()` call to install all of them. Like so:

```
fpaths = glob ("pkgs/*.tar.gz");
pkg ("install", fpaths{:});
```

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB and Octave both allow the easy syntax of

```
functionname arg1 arg2 ...
```

by translating it to the proper function call

```
functionname('arg1','arg2',...);
```

This implies that in order to pass the *value* of variables as arguments (rather than the variable *names* themselves), you must use the functional form:

```
pkgs = '../pkgs';
names = dir(fullfile(pkgs, '*.tar.gz')); 
n = numel(names);                    %// fixed your typo here
for k = 1:n
     pkg('install',names(k).name)    %// changed here, also n -> i -> k
end
```

Note that you had two typos: `names` was written as `nomes` in line 3 (translation issue, probably), and more importantly, you were using `n` rather than `i` in the loop. As a matter of fact, don't use `i` as a variable in Octave: that stands for the imaginary unit, and can lead to subtle errors if you're uncautious. I changed to `k` in the above code.

Comment: thanks a lot! This works. I forgot to translate some words really.

Comment: or you can make a single call to `pkg` with the names of all packages

Comment: @DarleisonRodrigues indeed, I suggest accepting carandraug's answer, as that's the proper way to do this.